# Determine missing values per ID based on a Table Column listing required values

Tags: sql, filter, missing-data

I have a 'Reqd_Values' Table that contains the following values:

```
Reqd_Items
----------
Part 1
Part 2
Part 3
Part 4
Part 5
```

Additionally, I have a separate 'Items_By_ID' table with the following data:

```
ID  | Item
--  | ----
1   | Part 1
1   | Part 2
1   | Part 3
1   | Part 4
2   | Part 1
2   | Part 2
2   | Part 4
2   | Part 5
3   | Part 2
3   | Part 4
3   | Part 5
```

I would like to check what values listed in the 'Reqd_Values' Table are missing, per 'ID', from the 'Item' column of the 'Items_By_ID' Table. The 'Result' Table should appear as follows:

```
ID  | Item
--  | ----
1   | Part 5
2   | Part 3
3   | Part 1
3   | Part 3
```

Any assistance with the SQL Query that would generate my 'Result' Table would be most appreciated.

Regards,

Wayne

Comment: Thanks, zip, Gordon and Programnik. I don't have my system available this evening, but I'll try each option out tomorrow when I do have access to my system and will then leave feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` or similar mechanism to filter out the ones that exist:

```
select i.id, r.item
from (select distinct id from Items_By_ID) i cross join
     req_items r left join
     Items_By_ID t
     on t.id = i.id and t.item_ = r.item_
where t.id is null
```

Comment: Tested and this query is exactly what I need. It works perfectly. Thanks very much Gordon, for providing this solution!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from Reqd_Values a where not exists(select 1 from Items_By_ID b where a.Reqd_Items = b.Item)
```

Comment: Does not do it by `ID`.

Comment: Tested and it is correct that the result is not produced by ID.

Answer (score -1):

```
select i.* 
  from reqd_items i 
       left join items_by_id d on i.item = d.item
 where d.item is null
```

Comment: Tested and the 'Reqd_Values' Table doesn't have an ID column, so the JOIN fails.